# One bad question about Christianity or Bible should be punished with a question ban?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, moderators, banning

I have 1 poorly received question and I am banned from asking questions here. Is there something wrong with my account here?

If you ask to many low quality answers on the SE websites you can get banned, but when it comes to asking questions about the Bible should there be a cap?

Comment: "Is X a sin" questions are not allowed here. Fortunately there is no such rule on meta.

Comment: If you wish to ask off-topic questions, there are plenty of other websites and chat rooms you can use on the Internet. The rules of this site are set in place by the community so that everyone can learn and get along. Banning people who don't cooperate doesn't stop those people from learning about the Bible.

Comment: Why do you think there shouldn't be a cap? Even though this site is not a church we would do well to heed 1 Corinthians 14:40: "But everything is to be done decently and in order."

Comment: Off: your PSE ban expires in 3 days. Come back!

Comment: @GraySheep yes but if i even fart i'm suspended for another year

Comment: @Muze Maybe yes, but be careful and keep a low activity. They won't cage you again without a warning, so if you get a warning, keep silent for at least some months.

Comment: @Muze Another thing, this time ontopic :-) Be careful. I think you are some U.S. protentant. I don't know too much about your denomination (I am catholic) but I think you should have some cleric, presbyter, priest to which you can go and you can ask anything from him. The Christianity SE doesn't (and can't) substitute him!!! If you are asking questions only on the Christinity SE, it is dangerous! Visit him, or meet him where you can, and talk also with him!

Comment: @Muze If you are active both on the Christinaty SE, but you are following him, it is okay. Of course only the CSE is better, as nothing.

Answer (score 5):

- You have experienced suspensions and question bans on multiple SE sites.
- I've seen poor quality questions from you here, on Aviation.SE, on EE.SE, and on Physics.SE
- I've seen questions from you on the metas for all the above sites and on the main Meta.SE asking about how question bans work, why you're still unable to ask after doing some work on your questions, and so on.  (links to some of them in a list below)
- I've seen good, helpful, thoughtful answers to those questions on the various meta sites.

The fact that you're asking this question is a strong indication that you aren't really getting how SE sites are intended to work, and especially how to ask appropriate questions.  Instead of asking essentially the same question on every meta.SE where you're active, you should read all the previous answers and really, really work on understanding how SE works.

Aviation.SE:

- https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3443/appealling-for-question-ban-to-be-lifted
- https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3459/question-ban-still-in-effect

Space Exploration.SE:

- https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/928/how-long-does-a-question-ban-last-here-in-my-case
- https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/934/may-i-be-forgiven-and-ask-questions-for-christmas
- https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/941/qustion-ban-still-in-effect

EE.SE:

- https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6414/my-question-banned-is-still-active-after-months
- https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6420/how-can-i-help-novice-in-electrical

For Physics.SE, there are too many meta questions to figure out which are the most relevant.  Apparently promptly after coming off of one suspension, another year-long suspension was handed out there:

- https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/148704/muze

Comment: Some cross-links to where this has been answered would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a Christianity SE answer, it is my own opinion (having nearly zero experience on this site).

Be careful with the Internet, anybody can say to you anything.

It is not a big problem, if you get, for example, some false information about the taste of the electrons. (It was only an example, I think you've got very high quality answers for your this question!)

Christianity SE, and any internet source, is dangerous if it is only information source.

**The site is useful to spread out the Message to the peoples of the Earth. Doing this is our obligation.** But that is it!

Never trust only it. Never ask any important here.

Ask your own cleric. Simply go to him, and ask him.

If you don't have one, or won't have a regular contact with a denomination, then use the site - it is better as nothing.

---

Now about your problem. SE sites tend to have a little continuous... troubles about, what is on-topic and what is not. The original intention of the SE founders was likely to decide these with votes. I would say, it is only a partial result. This leads to fights.

Fights in lesser important things, for example, should X be allowed on Y site, can be fought as usual. Typically, a "central mass" of the long-term and most active meta users and answerers decides. But also ordinary commoners have a little word, particularly if they are enough loud. :-) But as you don't make a heated debate in a temple, even in the (unheard) case that you would have the reason to do it, and so you don't make a heated debate on the CSE, too.

Another thing is that you should get back the same. You don't get it back, the software of the SE engine handled your downvoted or closed question like if you had asked some bad thing in physics. **It should not be allowed for a program to decide about Bible questions anything.**

This is another reason.

What you can ask from your local presbyter (?), ask him.

Use the CSE as an extension of your ordinary life, not instead it!

---

If you don't have a regular contact with him, then even the CSE is better as nothing.

Comment: this is a fine thing to answer, answers on meta should come from anyone, not just mods and high rep users.  I think you can undelete this.